# Technical term to describe/differentiate the structure of an instance by the number of samples per instance ('tuple' vs 'time series')

Tags: dataset, data, terminology

Several terms are used to describe the structure of instances of a dataset. For example, an instance can be '*univariate*' if it depends on only one variable or '*multivariate*' if it depends on 2 or more variables. I wonder if there are technical terms to distinguish the structure of a, let's call it a '*tuple*', and a '*time series*' or '*sequence*'.
Here are two examples that I am trying to describe or distinguish structurally:
[image]

The left example is a time series, where all 11 samples belong to one instance. The right example is a collection of 'tuples' (if that is the correct term), where each row represents a separate instance.

I always refer to the term '*tuple*' here, because the concept seems similar to me with the record in a database or the representation of points from mathematics. I am not sure if '*time series*' and '*tuple*' are the correct terms to describe how many samples an instance consists of. The terms should be analogous to uni/multivariate to describe the number of features in an instance.

Hence my question:
**If univariate/multivariate describes an instance in the horizontal, what terms are used to describe an instance vertically?**

Answer (score 1):

We have a **Dataset**

 Dataset has **Instances**

Instances can be a **Vector** Or a **Sequence**.

- If it is a vector, 
  It has **Features**

  *Examples - Image, Tabular data*
- If it is a Sequence, 
  It has **Time-steps**<sup>**</sup>

  Each Time-step can have Features *i.e. Uni/Multi-Variate*

  *Examples - Video, Audio, Time-series data*

<sup>**</sup>*When we use text-data as a sequence, we call the words as* "**Tokens**"

Comment: I conclude from the example with the image for the vectors that these are not only limited to 1-dimensional vectors, but can also be multi-dimensional (height x width x RGB channel) as in the case of colored images. Time steps, on the other hand, consist of a one-dimensional feature vector. Is that correct?

Comment: Time steps too can have multiple features e.g. If we measure Temperature, Pressure, Humidity from sensors. Similarly, think of video data. It's just has a temporal information across time steps. We can't shuffle the time steps randomly and make a sequence.